# Pass data from one page to another using Javascript works but page doesn't load

Tags: javascript

I have a page where there's a table with a button and when I click the button I store the value in a JS variable in order to send it to another page using post.

I get the values on the other page but after that the page does not load.

this is the button code to send the variable:

```
  <script>
function ObtenerDatosFila(oButton)
{
    var dgvVerGrupos = document.getElementById('dtBasicExample');

    $.ajax({
            url: 'FormularioAMGrupo.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 
            {
               Modificar:'Modificar', 
               IDGrupo:dgvVerGrupos.rows[oButton.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex].cells[0].innerHTML,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(){}
        });

        return false;
    }   

    </script>
</script>
```

Is there another easier a way to do this other than using post method?

Comment: Have you checked out `localStorage` yet? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage. Also are you getting any console errors on the page that doesn't load?

Comment: you need to add the data you have loaded , then reload your div element or page in success callback function

Comment: @justDan this is it! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make a one page site, no need to send the data around.
You'll have to change your structure a bit and change your ajax functions to a generic 'ShowPage(id)' function to achieve this.

If you are interested and need any help just say so.

Answer (score 0):

button's page:

```
<script>
function ObtenerDatosFila(oButton)
{
    var dgvVerGrupos = document.getElementById('dtBasicExample');

    localStorage.setItem("CodigoGrupo",dgvVerGrupos.rows[oButton.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex].cells[0].innerHTML);
    localStorage.setItem("Modificar",'Modificar');

    location.href ="FormularioAMGrupo.php";
}   
</script>
```

2nd page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem("CodigoGrupo"));
</script>
```